# Table partitioning with procedure input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to partitioning my table on ID which I got from procedure parameter.

For example my table ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE bigtable
  ( ID number )
```

As input procedure parameter I got eg. number: 130 , So I'm trying to create partition:

```
Alter table bigtable
add partition part_random_number values(random number);
```

Of course as random number I mean eg. 120,56 etc : )

But I got an error that object is not partitioned. So I tried to first defined partition clause in crate table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE bigtable
  ( ID  number )
 PARTITION BY list (ID)
```

But i doesn't work, It works when I defined some partition eg.

```
CREATE TABLE bigtable
      ( ID  number )
     PARTITION BY list (ID) 
(    partition type values(130);
)
```

But I would like to avoid it... Is there any other solution?

As result I would like to have table partitioned by procedure input parameterers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partitioned table has to have at least one partition. Just create it with a dummy partition and add the ones you actually need using your procedure.